# Ajax post in Wordpress contact form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and Ninja Form plugin.
I want to when I submit form, post to service datas.
HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="_ninja_forms_field_7" class="ninja-forms-field  popup-submit" id="ninja_forms_field_7" value="" rel="7">
```

JS:

```
$('#ninja_forms_field_7').click(function () {
    var name = $('#ninja_forms_field_6').val();
    var surname = $('#ninja_forms_field_6').val();
    var emailAddress = $('#ninja_forms_field_8').val();
    var eCommerceSiteUrl = $('#ninja_forms_field_9').val();




    var post_datas = emailAddress = +emailAddress & name = +name & surname = +surname & eCommerceSiteUrl = +eCommerceSiteUrl;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'myserviceaddress',
        data: post_datas,
        success: function (answer) {
            console.log(answer);
        }
    });
});
```

But not working.
How can I fix it?

Comment: what's  the error? Why do you say it's not working

Comment: data is plural in english from datum, datas is wrong, by the way

Comment: you need quotes in your `var post_datas` -> `var post_datas = "emailAddress="+emailAddress+"&name="+name+"&surname="+surname+"&eCommerceSiteUrl="+eCommerceSiteUrl;`

Answer (score 1):

```
 var post_datas = "emailAddress="+emailAddress+"&name="+name+"&surname" .....
```

You are missing the quote of your url post string (data).

or try better solution

```
var post_data = {name: name , email: email},

 $.ajax({data: postdata});
```